# Two values for same field with Jinja2 in Ansible

Tags: linux, tomcat, jinja2, ansible

I'm trying to set up a template in ansible, for our tomcat servers, but we have two tomcat instances on each host, each of which needs a different value for certain variables, for instance:

Tomcat_1 needs a port set to 8105
Tomcat_2 needs a port set to 8205

Easy enough to do if it's only one value per node needed, but I'm having some trouble finding how to do this when you need multiple values per host in either the Ansible or jinja2 docs. Can anyone offer some assistance, or point me to an example?

What I'm thinking is something along the lines of if this filepath then this value, but I'm not sure how to make that happen with jinja2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use two roles or use the role syntax that allows you to pass in values...

```
- { role: tomecat, some_parameter: 3 }
```